# After update from Angular 8 to Angular 9, 'ng generate component' generates a .css file instead of .scss

Tags: css, angular, sass

In my project I had set up SCSS as the style. Now after the update from Angular 8 to 9, when I use the CLI to generate a new component, a CSS file is generated where I expect an SCSS file to be generated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To fix it, open `angular.json` and search for `styleext` (it's in the schematics section). Rename `styleext` to `style`.

**Explanation**: This name has changed from `styleext` in version 8 to `style` in version 9 of Angular. However the `ng update` command did not take account of this. They have fixed it in the meantime so future `ng update`s will work properly:

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/16949

Comment: `ng config schematics.@nrwl/angular:component.style scss`

Comment: This doesn't work for me when generating modules. E.g., `ng g m pages/test7 --module app --route test7`.  It _does_ work when generating components.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify the already accepted answer:
As of Angular 9+ , I've fixed it in 'angular.json' file as follows: I've added/updated 'schematics' option as shown below

```
  "projects": {...},
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "style": "scss"
    }
  },
```